# Fatal Python error: PyImport_GetModuleDict: no module dictionary

Tags: python, multithreading, error-handling, python-module, python-multithreading

I have a script that makes calls to an API.  In order to speed the script up I've tried to implement threading.

The script below works when I'm in IDLE, however when I try to run it with a sys argv from the command line I received two types of errors listed below.

Error 1

```
Fatal Python error: PyImport_GetModuleDict: no module dictionary!

This application has requests the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.  Please         contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Error 2

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during iterpreter shutdown): 
Exception in thread Thread-2 (most likely raised during iterpreter shutdown):
Exception in thread Thread-3 (most likely raised during iterpreter shutdown):
Exception in thread Thread-5 (most likely raised during iterpreter shutdown):
```

I can't find anything on these errors.  So, any help is appreciated.  Below is the portion of the script that deals with threading.

```
import threading
import diffbot

urls = [[example.com],[example2.com]]
data = []

def getData(url):
        x = diffbot.classify(url)
    data.append(x)


def doWork(urls):
    for element in urls:
        for url in element:
            t = threading.Thread(target=getData, args=(url,))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

doWork(urls)
```

Comment: From googling that first error message I'm guessing you're on Windows. I'd add that information (maybe tag the question "windows" also). Also add: what Python version you are running, exactly how you are running the script, whether other Python scripts behave normally, whether interactive use of diffbot (i.e. in the Python shell) throws the error...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you run this as a stand alone script you have a lot of daemon threads in doWork, but the script will exit when only daemon threads are left, so they all get killed by the interpreter exiting.  When you run it interactively in IDLE the interpreter doesn't exit, so you don't run into that problem.

Answer (score 0):

This explains this error - https://bugs.python.org/issue26153 - not sure if it applies to you case though